# Unix permission to load a csv file into MySQL

Tags: centos

I am having problems trying to load my .csv file into MySQL on my Centos box.  My file is called 'OD_Orders.csv' is located in my home directory called /home/kam/KamSQLData

The error I get when I tried to load up the file into MySQL is:

**mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/kam/KamSQLData/OD_Orders.csv' INTO TABLE orders FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
ERROR 13 (HY000): File '/home/kam/KamSQLData/OD_Orders.csv' not found (Errcode: 13)**

I did some reading and the usual culprit is Unix permissions are off or wrong.  I than proceed to create a group (called KamSQLData) so the userid of 'mysql' and 'kam' can share the group on /home/kam/KamSQLData:

KamSQLData:x:512:mysql,kam

I then proceed to set /home/kam/KamSQLData as the group of 'KamSQLData', thinking both kam and mysql will have access to it.

```
-rwxr-xrwx.  1 root KamSQLData     2322 Feb 15 14:03 OD_Orders_2019-01-28.csv
-rwxr-xrwx.  1 root KamSQLData     5282 Feb 15 14:03 OD_Orders_2019-01-25.csv
-rwxr-xrwx.  1 root KamSQLData     4428 Feb 15 14:03 OD_Orders_2019-01-24.csv
-rwxr-xrwx.  1 root KamSQLData     9784 Feb 15 14:03 OD_Orders_2019-01-23.csv
-rwxr-xrwx.  1 root KamSQLData     3795 Feb 15 14:03 OD_Orders_2019-01-22.csv
-rwxr-xrwx.  1 root KamSQLData    11004 Feb 15 14:03 OD_Orders_2019-01-18.csv
-rwxr-xrwx.  1 root KamSQLData     3528 Feb 15 14:03 OD_Orders_2019-01-17.csv
-rwxr-xrwx.  1 root KamSQLData     5655 Feb 15 14:03 OD_Orders_2019-01-16.csv
-rwxr-xrwx.  1 root KamSQLData     2959 Feb 15 14:03 OD_Orders_2019-01-15.csv
-rwxr-xrwx.  1 kam  KamSQLData 27084955 Feb 15 14:21 OD_Orders.csv
drwx------. 12 kam  kam            4096 Feb 15 14:21 ..
drwxr-srwx.  2 root KamSQLData    20480 Feb 15 14:36 .
```

Than i went ahead and set the following to my directory:

**sudo chmod -R 2775 /home/kam/KamSQLData/**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89989/discussion-on-question-by-kam-unix-permission-to-load-a-csv-file-into-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

I ended taking the suggestion of Haxiel, where is never a good idea to make changes to the home directory (since everyone creation account(s) starts there). I placed my source data folder on /tmp and it already had the proper permission on that folder already (though I did run chmod -R 2775 to make sure). I was able to Load my .csv file(s) from that directory without modifying anything on SELinux or the home directory permission.